# sshd doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: ssh, centos, centos7

Yesterday I installed **LEMP** (php, mariaDB and so one) through SSH(Putty). Surprisingly  today SSH doesn't work anymore. I got the error connection established, so I looked it up on the internet and found that I had to start/restart sshd but if I run the command

```
service sshd start/restart
```

I'll get this error:

> Failed to issue methode call: Unit sshd.service failed to load: No such file or directory

So it looks like my SSH just disappeared. How can I fix that?

I'm running Centos7

Comment: Look if you have `/etc/init.d/sshd` file you can use that `/etc/init.d/sshd restart`

Comment: There is no sshd in /etc/init.d the only things there are: functions, netconsole, network and readme

Comment: @Michelem sorry i forgot to tagg you

Comment: Try to reinstall it: `yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients`

Comment: @Michelem Thank you so much :D it worked! i did this and enterd the command service sshd start and now it finally works!

Comment: I added my comment as answer for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall it: `yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients`